# Sorting in ascending order using the second column of a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm reading a CSV file that has information such as this residing inside of it:

```
ProcessID, Arrival Time, Burst Time
0,         1,            3
1,         0,            5
2,         9,            8
3,         10,           6
```

I'm trying to get it to look something more like this so that I can implement a FCFS algorithm

```
  ProcessID, Arrival Time, Burst Time
    1,        0,            5
    0,        1,            3
    2,        9,            8
    3,        10,           6
```

I've tried to see if I can just sort the arrival times:

```
n = len(processes) #amount of processes

for i in range(n):
    print(sorted(processes[i][1]))
```

However when print the sorted second column it returns 10 as ['0','1']`? E.g.

```
['1']
['0']
['9']
['0', '1']
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: are you sure you do not want to using pandas ?

Comment: I'm new to python and am not familiar with that library.

Comment: Maybe just check with that . Since what you need here, is just one function in `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be random commas in your data. Assuming those are fixed, what you are doing is calling `sorted` on *individual strings*, which sorts the *characters* in them.

Working on the following data:

```
0         ,1            ,3
1         ,0            ,5
2         ,9            ,8
3         ,10           ,6
```

This piece of code will get you what you want:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [[int(element) for element in row.split(',')] for row in string.replace(' ', '').split('\n')]
sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 5], 
 [0, 1, 3], 
 [2, 9, 8], 
 [3, 10, 6]]
```

That said, it would probably be better to use `pandas` to achieve this result, since then you could just do something like `pd.read_csv('data.csv').sort_values('Arrival Time')`.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm going to familiarize myself more with pandas.